# Ubuntu 18 inserting leading space to username

Tags: active-directory, user-accounts, samba4, ubuntu-18.04

We have an Ubuntu 18.04 client authenticating against a Samba 4 Active Directory.

On this client (and this client only) when a specific user (and this user only) logs in via ssh, tty, or the GUI (at the terminal) his user name and path to his home dir (which uses his user name) show a single additional space to the front of his name. This breaks his path to his home directory (since the name with the extra space doesn't exist).

Restart smbd and winbind corrects this, until the next reboot.

```
root@pc031:~# su - gxxxx
 gxxxx@pc031:~$
 gxxxx@pc031:~$
root@pc031:~# 

root@pc031:~# getent passwd | grep gxxxx
 gxxxx:*:1xx7:1x3::/common/homes/all/ gxxxx:/bin/bash
root@pc031:~#

root@pc031:~# getent passwd | less
(...snip...)
wxxxxxxx:*:1xx8:1x3::/common/homes/all/wxxxxxxx:/bin/bash
 gxxxx:*:1xx7:1x3::/common/homes/all/ gxxxx:/bin/bash
sxxxxxxxx:*:1xx9:1x3::/common/homes/all/sxxxxxxxx:/bin/bash
(...snip...)

root@pc031:~# service winbind stop
root@pc031:~# service smbd restart
root@pc031:~# service winbind start
root@pc031:~# getent passwd | grep gxxxx
gxxxx:*:1xx7:1x3::/common/homes/all/gxxxx:/bin/bash
root@pc031:~#
```

I have checked the Samba AD, and there is no additional space in his username or info.

This is only happening on this machine.